# Reduce a multi-dimensional array into a smaller multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, loops

I wanted to reduce a multi-dimensional array into a smaller multi-dimensional array. Let me post what I mean. Here is my input/starting array:

```
[
  [
    [ ["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"] ],
    [ ["Richard", "R"],  ["Michael", "S"] ],
  ],
  [
    [ ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"] ],
    [ ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"] ]
  ]
]
```

And I think this is the four dimensional array which I want to reduce to:

```
["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"], ["Richard", "R"],  ["Michael", "S"], ["Allen", "S"],["Omer", "P"] , ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: You can just loop through all these levels and build your result. Have you tried that? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: But `Array#flatten` does it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array#flatten(levels)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
xs.flatten(2)
```

Comment: @tokland: This returns => ["Armando", "P", "Dave", "S", "Richard", "R", "Michael", "S", "Allen", "S", "
Omer", "P", "David E.", "R", "Richard X.", "P"]

Comment: I want to maintain the last level !!

Comment: @CSSS: are you sure? I just tested it in a console, taking the array verbatim from your question, you need two flattenings. Anyway, check `flatten(1)`.

Comment: Still there is some level of nesting that remains

Comment: Sorry..  my fault. Your solution is perfect !